# Is there a way to do SMS from the PC with iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, windows, sms

Is there a way to implement handoff to iOS so my PC running windows can send iMessage/SMS through bluetooth and iOS cellular data connections. This is analogous to MightyText on PC does  to Android hardware and cellular service.

I know I can do iMessage on the Mac, but I do not own that hardware and would also like to do SMS from my PC over iOS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/176818/how-can-i-send-sms-from-my-pc-using-my-iphone

Comment: Could you edit this to explain how it relates to iOS or Apple products? It seems any SMS that the carrier allows will be delivered to any phone - not an iPhone so this might be better suited on SuperUser since it's basically how to go from Windows OS to SMS network.

Answer (score 4):

There is currently no way to send SMS from a PC or a Mac.

As you mentioned you can currently send iMessages from a Mac, and you will be able to send both iMessages and SMS from a Mac once OS X Yosemite is released (according to [apple.com](http://www.apple.com/osx/preview/))

**EDIT:**

A quick Google search for "send iphone sms from pc" found this: http://www.myphonedesktop.com/

Comment: Yes, I saw MyPhoneDesktop as well.  But I don't think it works the way I think it should.  In other words, I think all it does, is let you type your text message from the PC, press Send, it pops up the Messages app and you will have to pick who you will send stuff to and press Send.  I might be wrong, but there is no way to try this since the app is $5.  I don't want to waste money on something that works like that.

Comment: And in addition, it doesn't seem like it actually receives text messages.

Comment: There does not currently seem to be a way, unless your phone is jailbroken. See the SU thread for details.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are really looking for is a way to do iMessage from a windows computer.  iMessage is not the same thing as SMS.  SMS has a lot of limitations compared to iMessage which is why Apple created iMessage.

There are some sketchy looking tools that claim to do this on Windows, but I suggest caution.

Comment: I think he wants both actually. Your solution works for iMessage, but not SMS. Solves a half though.

Comment: Even on Mac OS X or an iPad, you can't send SMS messages from iMessage.  That capability is only available on the iPhone.  To send an SMS on anything other then a cell phone you need some kind of conversion.  A common way to do this is to send an email to an address formatted like [phonenumber]@mms.att.net.  Of course, it's specific to the carrier.

Comment: Or do something like Continuity where it uses the phone.

Comment: This program looks really sketchy.  Like a virus sketchy.

Comment: Agreed, I didn't look at it too closely, but on second look I wouldn't recommend installing it until some more investigation can be done.  I've edited my post to remove the URL.

Answer (score -4):

You can send SMS from your computer.  Use mysms.com, register your mobile number and login through that.  After that, you can send sms from your computer, which will get routed through your phone, which means you have to have your phone and the computer connected to the internet.  This works with Android OS.

For MAC, there is only one way, i.e. to use iMessage.  I hope this helps.

Comment: How does this use iOS. S fits better on a question for PC and Android?

Comment: You answered relating to Android, asker wants iOS.